# How to repeat a geospatial function multiple times, insert the results into a new column using data from the same and upcoming row

Tags: sql, geospatial, amazon-athena

I am very new to SQL and need help to perform the following 3-part query.

First, I am using Athena on AWS, engine version 2.0. In order to calculate a distance between two geographical points (lat, long), I use the following function:

```
SELECT ST_Distance
(to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(48.064633, 16.165786)), 
 to_spherical_geography(ST_Point(48.065501, 16.166477)))
```

and this works.

Now, I would need to automatize the process.
My table looks as follows:

```
**lat         long     user_id                      timestamp**

48.064633   16.165786  978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a  2020-03-21 23:36:28

48.065501   16.166477  978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a  2020-03-21 23:36:33

48.06637    16.167177  978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a  2020-03-21 23:36:38

48.067426   16.168007  978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a  2020-03-21 23:36:44
```

...

First, I would like to perform the mentioned geospatial calculation using the lat, long entries from the first and second row, and insert the result in a new column called "distance".
Then, I want to repeat this automatically for the second and third row, third and fourth, and so on.

Therefore, my questions are: how can I perform the st_distance function using values from a specific row? How can I insert the result into a new column? And, how can I repeat this process for every upcoming row? Preferably done in one query.

Any help would be highly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How do you want to calculate the distance? Always to the previous point or to a fixed location? How is your table called?

Comment: I want to calculate the distance by always using the lat, long values from the actual row and the next one. Let's call the table 'distance_calculator'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things ambiguous about your question, so I'll take some guesses.

> First, I would like to perform the mentioned geospatial calculation
> using the lat, long entries from the first and second row,

In SQL, the table is just an unordered collection of rows, there is no concept of first and second rows. To make `first and second row` meaningful, you need some order. I'll assume these should be ordered by timestamp.

> and insert the result in a new column called "distance".

This makes a computation between two rows, and inserts the result into a new column. But which row do you want to be updated with this result, should the distance between first and second row go to `distance` column of first row, or second row? I'll assume you want **later** row updated.

Now, most SQL computations either apply to current row, or to aggregate of all rows in a table, or in a group. To do pairwise computation you need analytic functions. Function `LAG` returns value of the data in the previous row (after rows have been ordered some way).

Your query to produce the result you need will be something like (I don't use Athena, so I'll use Google BigQuery dialect, but all SQL engines have similar concepts).

```
WITH data_with_prev AS (
-- first, we add previous point coordinates, prev_long and prev_lat to each row
select 
  *, 
  LAG(long) OVER(order by timestamp) prev_long,
  LAG(lat) OVER(order by timestamp) prev_lat
from tmp.so
)
-- now we compute the distance between current point and previous point
SELECT 
  lat, long, user, timestamp, 
  ST_Distance(ST_GeogPoint(prev_long, prev_lat), 
              ST_GeogPoint(long, lat)) as dist
FROM data_with_prev
```

The result is (row order is arbitrary, here sorted by timestamp for demo):

List item

```
lat         long        user                        timestamp               dist
48.064633   16.165786   978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a 2020-03-21 23:36:28 UTC 
48.065501   16.166477   978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a 2020-03-21 23:36:33 UTC 109.32633779807787
48.06637    16.167177   978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a 2020-03-21 23:36:38 UTC 109.73952619883725
48.067426   16.168007   978de2aa4f0ec83b@@@b5abda0a 2020-03-21 23:36:44 UTC 132.63395869669478
```

Comment: I am going to add now a new primary key, but this has already solved my problem. Thank you a lot!